# How to get the class name when running a constructor function in duktape?

Tags: duktape

I'd like to use a single duktape/C constructor function as dispatcher for these kind of calls. When the dispatcher function is called I need to know for which class this happend to call the appropriate C++ construction function.

I guess the `this` binding won't help since it represents the (not yet fully initialized) JS object we are creating here.

Another option would be the current function, but from the docs I can't see how to get the class name from that. What else could I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you elaborate what you mean by "class name"? Do you mean the `.name` property of the Ecmascript function object which is used as a the 'new' target?

If so, you can use `duk_is_constructor_call()` to see if the current call is a constructor call, then use `duk_push_current_function()` to get access to the Ecmascript constructor function object, and then read its properties using the usual property API calls. For example, if by "class name" you mean `.name` of the function object, you'd just read its "name" property using duk_get_prop_string().

Comment: I wasn't sure there's such a property and unfortunately, I'm currently focused on something else, so I didn't came around to test this. But your suggestion sounds reasonable.

Comment: Function objects created with duk_push_c_function() don't have a `name` property automatically but you can set it manually (and should do so in this case). Function objects created from Ecmascript code as `function foo() {...}` have a `.name` property automatically.